# Formatting .txt documents with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, txt

I am trying to brush up on Python & I have come to a halt with figuring out how to deal with .txt documents. I am challenging myself to make a program that can calculate GPA.

I decided to make my program a little more complicated and instead of a list I want to read a .txt and scrape the relevant information out of it and turn it into a list. I want the list in the format:
(`list = [Grades, Credits]`  `list = [97.0, 3.0]`)

How do I target only the information I want? I have tried a couple things, but each have their own minuet issue, so I will share the code that got me closest to my end point.  My code/output & .txt is as follows:

Please let me know if I any other information is needed to make better sense of what I am attempting & Thank you!

Code:

```
digits = []
n = 0
digit_str = ""
with open("Grades.txt", "r") as g_c_txt:
    lines = g_c_txt.readlines()
    print(lines)

for line in lines:
    for i in line:
        if (i.isdecimal() or i == "." or i == "|") == True:            
            if (n == 0):
                i = ""
                n += 1
            digit_str += i

digits = digit_str.split("|")

print()
print(digits)
```

Output:

```
['Government | 97.0% | 3.0 Credits |\n', 'History | 87.0% | 3.0 Credits |\n', 'College Algebra | 76.0% | 4.0 Credits |\n', 'Trignometry | 93.0% | 3.0 Credits |\n', 'Pre-Calculus | 83.0% | 4.0 Credits |\n', 'English 1 | 75.0% | 3.0 Credits |\n', 'Calculus 1 | 56.6% | 4.0 Credits |\n', 'English 2 | 89.4% | 3.0 Credits |']

['97.0', '3.0', '', '87.0', '3.0', '', '76.04.0', '', '93.0', '3.0', '', '83.0', '4.0', '1', '75.0', '3.0', '1', '56.6', '4.0', '2', '89.4', '3.0', '']
```

.txt:

```
Government | 97.0% | 3.0 Credits |
History | 87.0% | 3.0 Credits |
College Algebra | 76.0% | 4.0 Credits |
Trignometry | 93.0% | 3.0 Credits |
Pre-Calculus | 83.0% | 4.0 Credits |
English 1 | 75.0% | 3.0 Credits |
Calculus 1 | 56.6% | 4.0 Credits |
English 2 | 89.4% | 3.0 Credits |
```

If I get the text using `txt_text.readlines()` and use a for loop to iterate and check if each is a decimal using `i.isdecimal()` it nearly works except I don't understand how to get rid of multiple extra "|". It also grabs "1, 1, 2" from "English 1, Calculus 1, and English 2". I know I could make this easier by simplifying the .txt, but I won't always be able to choose the format I get my data in and want to learn how to process a bit more complicated documents.

Comment: Have you already tried splitting each line into columns, and then adding up grades and credit?

Comment: You can do that? How do you seperate a line into columns? I didn't realize that way something you could do lol.

Comment: @GildedWasp, For that you have to import module. You seem to be a beginner. So, forget about that at present. Once you get familiarised with basic data structures, then you can go for it.

Comment: I'm assuming `College Algebra | 76.0% - 4.0 Credits |` is supposed to be `College Algebra | 76.0% | 4.0 Credits |`?

Comment: it also isn't exactly clear what format you want for the output. Why don't you just give the corresponding output to your example input?

Comment: It's fixed. I'll add what I expect but @SuramuthuR pretty much got it spot on. I don't need the "Goverment" or "Credits" in the output but that's an easy enough fix with what he's given me.

Comment: Wait, I do have what output I want in there already - "I want the list in the format: (list = [Grades, Credits] list = [97.0, 3.0])"

Comment: Only thing I didn't make clear is I would like them to be floats.

Comment: I didn't down vote anything???

Comment: I just earned voters privileges, so I upvoted all the answers thank you all for your help in this matter. I will be trying out several things to learn a bit. Idk why they downvoted, but at least it's reset to 0 now!

Comment: somebody also downvoted my post

Answer (score 1):

When you approach any problem in programming, *split your abstractions into modular units*.

We know that we want to process the text file line by line. Your format is basically a csv that usees "|" as a delimiter. We can use `str.split` to extract each "cell" into a list.

Then from the second and third cells on each line, we want to extract the decimal string. We could use `re` to do this, but if your input is regular, a simple approach is also possible, which keeps the spirit of your original attemp. We put the characters into a `set`, although, you could just use a `str` as well in this particular case.

So we want to process each line as a delimited list, and extract decimal numbers we assume will be in the second and third cells.

```
DECIMAL_CHARS = set('0123456789.')
GRADE_POS = 1
CREDIT_POS = 2

def extract_number(item: str) -> str:
    """
    filters out any character that isn't a decimal digit or decimal point
    """
    result = []
    for c in item:
        if c in DECIMAL_CHARS:
            result.append(c)
    return ''.join(result)

def process_line(line: str) -> tuple[float, float]:
    cells = [cell.strip() for cell in line.split('|')]
    grade = float(extract_number(cells[GRADE_POS]))
    credits = float(extract_number(cells[CREDIT_POS]))
    return grade, credits

with open("grades.txt") as f:
    records = [process_line(line) for line in f]

print(records)
```

If I were actually faced with this task, I would probably use a combination of `csv` and `re`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the the `csv` library for splitting up the fields:

```py
with open("Grades.txt") as stream:
    reader = csv.reader(stream, delimiter="|")
    rows = list(reader)
    pprint.pprint(rows)
```

Output:

```
[['Government ', ' 97.0% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['History ', ' 87.0% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['College Algebra ', ' 76.0% ', ' 4.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['Trignometry ', ' 93.0% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['Pre-Calculus ', ' 83.0% ', ' 4.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['English 1 ', ' 75.0% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['Calculus 1 ', ' 56.6% ', ' 4.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['English 2 ', ' 89.4% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', '']]
```

For each row, we can write a short function to parse it. The goal is to convert a row such as

```
[['Government ', ' 97.0% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', '']
```

to

```
[97.0, 3.0]
```

That function is

```py
def parse(row: list[str]):
    # Convert ' 97.0% ' --> 97.0
    grade = float(row[1].strip().removesuffix("%"))

    # Convert ' 3.0 Credits ' -> 3.0
    credit = float(row[2].split()[0])

    return [grade, credit]
```

Putting it together:

```py
import csv
import pprint


def parse(row: list[str]):
    # Convert ' 97.0% ' --> 97.0
    grade = float(row[1].strip().removesuffix("%"))

    # Convert ' 3.0 Credits ' -> 3.0
    credit = float(row[2].split()[0])

    return [grade, credit]


with open("Grades.txt") as stream:
    reader = csv.reader(stream, delimiter="|")
    rows = list(reader)
    pprint.pprint(rows)

    output = [parse(row) for row in rows]
    pprint.pprint(output)
```

Output:

```
[['Government ', ' 97.0% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['History ', ' 87.0% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['College Algebra ', ' 76.0% ', ' 4.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['Trignometry ', ' 93.0% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['Pre-Calculus ', ' 83.0% ', ' 4.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['English 1 ', ' 75.0% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['Calculus 1 ', ' 56.6% ', ' 4.0 Credits ', ''],
 ['English 2 ', ' 89.4% ', ' 3.0 Credits ', '']]
[[97.0, 3.0],
 [87.0, 3.0],
 [76.0, 4.0],
 [93.0, 3.0],
 [83.0, 4.0],
 [75.0, 3.0],
 [56.6, 4.0],
 [89.4, 3.0]]
```

Notes

- Using the `csv` library, we can break up each lines into `rows`, which is a list of strings.
- The function `parse` should be easy to understand: it strip off everything but digit and dots, then convert to float the two fields we are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Please Note: the line 3 of 'a.txt' you 've given as `College Algebra | 76.0% - 4.0 Credits |` which does not match the format of other lines. So correct the type error to `College Algebra | 76.0% | 4.0 Credits |`.

In your question the format of the required output is not clear. So, I'm giving as multidimensional list

```
f = open('a.txt', 'r')
lst = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i in range(len(lst)):
    
    #Add an extra '|' before 'credits'
    lst[i] = lst[i].replace(' Credits', ' | Credits')
    
    #Convert each line into list
    lst[i] = lst[i].split('|')
    
    #remove unwanted characters
    for j in range(len(lst[i])):
            lst[i][j] = lst[i][j].replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '').replace('%', '')

l = []

#iterate thru list
for x in lst:
    # a new sublist containing 2 lists, in each list the 2nd element is value
    sub = [[x[0], int(float(x[1]))], [x[3], int(float(x[2]))]]
    l.append(sub)

print(l)

'''Output:
[[['Government', 97], ['Credits', 3]], [['History', 87], ['Credits', 3]], [['CollegeAlgebra', 76], ['Credits', 4]], [['Trignometry', 93], ['Credits', 3]], [['Pre-Calculus', 83], ['Credits', 4]], [['English1', 75], ['Credits', 3]], [['Calculus1', 56], ['Credits', 4]], [['English2', 89], ['Credits', 3]]]
'''
```

In case if you want keys in a list and values in a list in the output list, change the line 22 to `sub = [[x[0], x[3]], [int(float(x[1])), int(float(x[2]))]]`

Comment: I will take a look at this when I get off from work. Sorry about the txt error I was changing the symbols to try different things and missed changing one back. I was going to use "-" but there's one in "pre-calculus" so I thought it wouldn't be possible to do. Thank you for your time!

Comment: This makes a ton more sense now. You basically turned the extra "|" at the back of each into an empty index in the list, then formatted the list to give only the indexes of the list that have the needed information into a new list. That's fantastic!